# Show only parent when segment 3 is active and dynamic

Tags: categories, parent, child-categories, children

I have a simple entry with categories and children.

Parent A
  Child A
  Child B

When an entry is set to ONLY Parent A I want that entry to display.  BUt what happens is the children entry is displayed instead.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="on" limit="1"}
{content}{/exp:channel:entries}

http://domain.com/home/Classes/category/parent-a
```

in the example above the child category a displays instead of Parent A

Answer (score 1):

auto-assign category to parents set to NO fixed it